# Breadth First Search in maze , how can i calculate the states?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I'am confused to get a way for programming a BFS algorithm for a maze ,

I know that i need a queue for it , but my problem is how can i generates the states ?

for example , The maze contains A robot and Holes , and blocks

let the following is the initial state :

```
R BBB
   H 
   H 

  B G
```

where the space is empty cells ( the robot can walk through ) 
and B is block and H is hole ,

My question is , to use a BFS i need a graph ( or corresponding tree )

but i don't know how can i generate these states ?

to clear my question , let the initial state above be a state A

how can i find the states B,C,D ...... etc ?

to apply the BFS algorithm

i hope the question is clear ,

thank you ALL

Answer (score 0):

If a maze is a grid, a state is a pair of two numbers: the row index and the column index. The neighbors of (r, c) are (r-1, c), (r, c-1), (r, c+1), (r+1, c). You can maintain a queue of pairs to run a breadth-first search on your maze.